# Как отключить ipv6 dns запросы в dnsmasq?

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

На моем хостинге ipv6 отключен на уровне sysctl, но dnsmasq по прежнему шлет dns запросы ipv6.
И, как правило, эти запросы все равно не получают ответов, т.к. AAAA записи нет.

Вот как это выглядит в логе:

```
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[8184]: query[SRV] _minecraft._tcp.fcraft.su from 127.0.0.1
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[8184]: forwarded _minecraft._tcp.fcraft.su to 8.8.8.8
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: query[A] fcraft.su from 127.0.0.1
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: forwarded fcraft.su to 8.8.8.8
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: reply fcraft.su is 190.115.29.78
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: query[AAAA] fcraft.su from 127.0.0.1
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: forwarded fcraft.su to 8.8.8.8
Oct 30 20:38:41 dnsmasq[12684]: reply fcraft.su is NODATA-IPv6
```

Я хочу, чтобы были только `query[A]` запросы, а `query[AAAA]` не было.

Тестил с параметром `min-cache-ttl=120`, не помогает, ничего не менятся.

Comment: [как-то через задний проход](https://gist.github.com/noseka1/6b7cbeca199db9c4823324bc31214bb2)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ок спасибо